# Color detection and analyasis

Tags: delphi, image-processing, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to analyse a .Jpeg Image 600x600, but doing so I want it to tell me where the RED value is above 230 and Green value above 200.
Right now I have this project going on, but it takes too long to iterate the whole image, and getting strange value of pixel color (`Color= + inttostr(RGB)`).
Could anyone lend me a hand?

```
type
  PRGBTripleArray = ^TRGBTripleArray;
  TRGBTripleArray = array[0..4095] of TRGBTriple;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RGB: Byte;
  X, Y: Integer;
  R, G, B: Byte;
  Bitmap1: TBitmap;
  ColorRGB: LongInt;
  Pixels: PRGBTripleArray;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Bitmap1 := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap1.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);

    for Y := 0 to Bitmap1.Height - 1 do
    begin
      Pixels:= Bitmap1.ScanLine[Y];

      Memo1.Lines.Add('======================');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Line # ' + IntToStr(Y));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('======================');

      for X := 0 to Bitmap1.Width - 1 do
      begin
        ColorRGB := ColorToRGB(Bitmap1.Canvas.Pixels[x, y]);
        R := GetRValue(ColorRGB);
        G := GetGValue(ColorRGB);
        B := GetBValue(ColorRGB);
        RGB:= R*G*B;

        Memo1.Lines.Add(
                'line='    + IntToStr(Y)
              + ' row='    + IntToStr(X)
              + ' Colour=' + IntToStr(RGB)
              + ' Red='    + IntToStr (R) // red
              + ' Green='  + IntToStr (G) // blue
              + ' Blue='   + IntToStr (B) // green
        )
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Bitmap1.free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I don't get `RGB:= R*G*B;` at all. Why do you compute the product?! Also, you might need to set the pixel format.

Comment: The colors vary from [0 to 16581375(255*255*255)] in RGB values, I shouldn't do that product `R*G*B`, but how's the solution if sometimes a value is 0?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  how do I set the pixel format?

Comment: At least you're using `Byte` data type for this, what logically exceed the max. value of 255. Better try to describe, what you're going to do. I'm quite out from description *"I want it to tell me where the RED value is above 230 and Green value above 200"*. You want to log each pixel having red value greater than 230 and green value greater than 200 ?

Comment: @Ammadeux: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If you have bytes `R`, `G`, and `B`, and want the corresponding colour, do `Windows.RGB(R, G, B)`. This is the same as `B shl 16 + G shl 8 + R`. You can also use `or` instead of `+`.

Comment: `Bitmap1.PixelFormat := pf24bit`

Comment: @TLama, as I have the Lines showing the value of each pixel in it. I want it to show only the pixels where its value of RED and GREEN are above 230 and 200 respectively

Comment: Your code is slow because you are updating the memo control text for every pixel and the memo control is redrawing itself immediately before execution can continue with the next pixel. TLama's code is faster because Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate disables all redrawing of the memo control during the pixel loop.

Comment: @dthorpe, much more slower will the code be due to use of `Canvas.Pixels` access to bitmap pixels, I'd say, but that unlocked (potentially frequent) update of memo content is also a performance eater of course.

Comment: True, I had missed the reference to the Pixels[] array.  I wish we had never exposed pixels that way. ;>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to log every pixel of your bitmap, which has red channel value greater than 230 and green value greater than 200, you might use the following. Don't forget to use `BeginUpdate`, `EndUpdate` pair for `TMemo.Lines` to lock potential frequent updating.

Anyway, you are still mixing two bitmap pixel access techniques together. Do not use `Canvas.Pixels` for large pixel array manipulation; it's very inefficient. Use only `ScanLine` for that:

```
type
  PRGBTripleArray = ^TRGBTripleArray;
  TRGBTripleArray = array[0..4095] of TRGBTriple;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  C: TColor;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  Pixels: PRGBTripleArray;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);

    Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    try
      for Y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
      begin
        Pixels := Bitmap.ScanLine[Y];
        for X := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
        begin
          if (Pixels[X].rgbtRed > 230) and (Pixels[X].rgbtGreen > 200) then
          begin
            C := RGB(
              Pixels[X].rgbtRed,
              Pixels[X].rgbtGreen,
              Pixels[X].rgbtBlue
            );
            Memo1.Lines.Add(
              '===============' + sLineBreak +
              'Pixel[' + IntToStr(X) + '; ' + IntToStr(Y) + ']' + sLineBreak +
              'Color: ' + ColorToString(C) + sLineBreak +
              'Red channel: ' + IntToStr(Pixels[X].rgbtRed) + sLineBreak +
              'Green channel: ' + IntToStr(Pixels[X].rgbtGreen) + sLineBreak +
              'Blue channel: ' + IntToStr(Pixels[X].rgbtBlue)
            );
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `DupeString('=', 15)` undeclared identifier

Comment: @Ammadeux: Add `StrUtils` to your `uses` clause.

Comment: Works pretty well, and fast. Altough, how do I get the color value, instead of `Color: $002CD2FB`

Comment: Do you mean a decimal representation of a `TColor` ? If so, then use `IntToStr(Integer(C))`.

Comment: Thanks TLama, got it How I want it.